# Selenium Webdriver is unable to communicate with Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

my chrome version updated to the latest v110.0.5481.178.
since then, I keep getting the following error when initializing Selenium ChromeDriver.
Specifically when initializing the new `ChromeDriver` as follow.

The error though is: `The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:58801/session timed out after 60 seconds.`

Nothing has changed and the same code works on a different laptop using the exact same chrome version. so I'm confused.

```
  var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
                    co.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.clipboard", 1);

                    co.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", m_downloadDirectory);
                    co.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
                    co.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
                    co.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");

                    string ChromeDriverLocalEnvironmentVariable = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CHROMEWEBDRIVER", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
                    string chromeDriverPath = ChromeDriverLocalEnvironmentVariable != null ? ChromeDriverLocalEnvironmentVariable : AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                    m_driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, co);
```

I have tried several solutions including some chrome settings changes such as disabling `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`.

In addition, I have noticed that a new pop-up appears every time I'm opening the browser(either manually or using selenium).
The pop- up message: `Restore Pages - Chrome didn't shut down correctly`
I managed to get rid of it after clearing the cache but the above HTTP error still remains (the pop-up appears again after opening the browser again several times).

Chrome version : v110.0.5481.178

Chromedriver version: 110.0.5481.7700

Selenium version: 3.141.0

I have also tried creating a new project with the simple following code but the error keep showing

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set up the Chrome driver
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            // Navigate to Google.com
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

            // Do something with the page here

            // Close the browser
            driver.Quit();
        }
```

as well as disabling the entire extensions.

This is the CMD starts and I think something is missing.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}) on port 64437
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64478/devtools/browser/e7cfe558-6c8a-473b-a6ac-ca72a0f60d4c
```

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Anti-virus software? Firewall softare? It feels like some other software component on that machine is interfering.